# Is this function involving indicator function Lipschitz?

Tags: lipschitz-functions

Is this function $$x1_{\{x>0\}}(x)$$ Lipschitz? It's not differential so mean value cant be used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You only need $|f(x)-f(y)| \le K |x-y|$, and $K=1$ will do.

Comment: please explain your reasoning, I cant see why.

Comment: @Vaolter: Have you sketched a graph of your function?

Comment: Evaluate both sides, taking cases (i) $x,y>0$, (ii) $x,y<0$ etc in turn

Comment: Yes. Or draw it.

Comment: @Richard Martin, Ok, thank you, I have checked it.